# Принудительное обновление страницы

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код на сайте, который меняет значение переменной в зависимости от того на какой див нажали (я не буду загромождать вопросом не нужным кодом). В зависимости от значения переменной меняется некоторые элементы оформления сайта.

Проблема в том, что предположим пользователь открыл две страницы сайта. Одну обычную и вторую где можно изменить оформление (т.е. переменную). Он её изменил, вторая страница автоматически обновилась (благодаря пустой ссылки) и он увидел результат, который его удовлетворил. Он перешёл на открытую первую страницу, но там то изменений нет пока не обновишь страницу. Как сделать так, чтобы при переходе на открытую страницу, она проверяла изменилась ли переменная и в зависимости от этого обновляла страницу автоматически или нет?

Спасибо!

Comment: интервалы слишком большие, перезагрузив страницу, ты опять попадаешь в этот интервал и опять перезагружаешься и так почти час, пользователь даже сделать ничего не успеет, будет постоянная перезагрузка

Comment: аа.. т.е. он каждую минуту условия проверяет и соответственно будет обновлять страницу?

Comment: нет, не каждую минуту, а при каждой загрузке.

Comment: а, я понял Вас..

Comment: хорошо, а если убрать эти условия со временем.. у пользователя открыты две страницы сайта. На одной странице он изменил переменную и перешёл на вторую страницу, то на ней он не увидит изменения пока страница не перезагрузится. Поэтому, все же как сделать принудительное обновление? Чтобы при переходе на вторую страницу она проверила изменилась ли переменная и перезагрузилась при необходимости? Или для этого лучше отдельный вопрос на сайте задать?

Comment: лучше отредактировать этот, добавив в него всю необходимую информацию

Comment: для принятия изменений на лету нужно использовать веб-сокеты.